# Why the output is different without using function

Tags: javascript, html, web

I output same for first two output with and without using function but output is different for 3rd and 4th ouputs.why ?
I hope the logic is same with and without using functions

```js
var string = "Welcome to this Javascript Guide!";
// Output becomes !ediuG tpircsavaJ siht ot emocleW
var reverseEntireSentence = reverseBySeparator(string, "");
console.log(reverseEntireSentence)
var res = string.split("").reverse().join("")
console.log(res)
    // Output becomes emocleW ot siht tpircsavaJ !ediuG
var reverseEachWord = reverseBySeparator(reverseEntireSentence, " ");
console.log(res.split("").reverse().join(""))
console.log(reverseEachWord)


function reverseBySeparator(string, separator) {
    return string.split(separator).reverse().join(separator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are passing as separator a white space string (" ")

```js
var reverseEachWord = reverseBySeparator(reverseEntireSentence, " ");
```

By this way you will get the expected output:

```js
var reverseEachWord = reverseBySeparator(reverseEntireSentence, "");
```

Comment: can'nt understand

Comment: the second argument of reverseBySeparator defines the separator

Comment: i found this on the internet so can you tell me what actually happened here in this program .(step by step)

Comment: And why "" not consider as space string

Comment: check MDN string methods split() and join(), if you split(" ") you are creating an array from string separated by spaces (words), if you split("") you are creating an array from string separated by letters.